# How can i remove underline from edittext line though have already background

Tags: android, xml

```
     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/idLogin"
        android:layout_below="@+id/signintitle"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/calibri_bold"
        android:background="@drawable/editbox"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/slogan_color"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:hint="@string/id"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        android:textColorHint="@color/slogan_color"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp" />
```

I have a background drawable already, so how can I remove the edittext underline?Check the image for more details.

Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
txtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail); txtEmail.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

if this not work try this one

```
android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
```

or

```
.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
```

Comment: `android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"` work for me. Also try convert `EditText` to `AppCompatEditText`